# Changing mysql dump to not include the auto-inc column

Tags: mysql, bash, unix, sed

I have a mysqldump file which I'd like to restore, but not the same way as it's built. It contains an auto-increment column which I'd like to remove.

The dump file looks like this: (first column is the auto-inc)

```
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES (833899644,461796098,'Wed',21,12),(833899645,423455772,'Sun',3,3)
...
```

So I was thinking I'll need to change that to: (remove first number)

```
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES (461796098,'Wed',21,12),(423455772,'Sun',3,3)
```

This dump is pretty big (20GB) but I assume sed can handle that pretty easily, but not sure how. Would appreciate a solution for sed / other option.

Comment: I think you forgot to remove the first number for the second group of values in your expected output.

Comment: You are right, corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep it simple, remove everything from a left parentheses up to the first comma.

If your want the change to happen in place use:

```
sed -i -r "s/\([^,]+,/\(/g" file
```

If you want to save it in another file:

```
sed -r "s/\([^,]+,/\(/g" file > outfile
```

Comment: This seems to work, how can I keep the original file? Tried this: `cat file | sed -i -r "s/\([^,]+,/\(/g" > new_file` but it didn't work

Comment: @Noam remove the `-i` that is the in-place flag and redirect the stdout to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below sed command to remove the first number along with the following comma,

```
sed 's/^\([^0-9]*\)[0-9]\+,\(.*\)$/\1\2/g' file
```